# Extract the "modified date" column data to an excel for anumber of document

Tags: c#, file, window, ms-office

My scenario : I have lots of documents found in folders and its related sub folder.

I want to be able to read and save the "modified date" column of each document to an excel file. After this step i am going to perform some conversion to the files that will eventually change the "modified date" column and i will use that excel file to restore the "modified date" column to its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

But instead of storing the list in excel, I have have serialized the object and stored as Binary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;

namespace stackoverflow
{
class Program
{
    private static List<String> fileNameList = new List<String>();
    private static List<DateTime> fileDateList = new List<DateTime>();
    private static List<String> filename;
    private static List<DateTime> fileDate;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sDir = "C:\\Work\\DUke_Tee";
        DirSearch(sDir);
        ListSerialize();
        //ListDeserialize();
        Console.WriteLine("done");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
            {
                DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(f);
                DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(f);
                files.Add(f);
                fileNameList.Add(f);
                fileDateList.Add(modification);
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
        return files;
    }


    public static void ListSerialize()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Work\\dataName.bin", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(stream, fileNameList);
            }
            using (Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Work\\dataDate.bin", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(stream, fileDateList);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void ListDeserialize()
    {    
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Work\\dataName.bin", FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                filename = (List<String>)bin.Deserialize(stream);                   
            }
            using (Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Work\\dataDate.bin", FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                fileDate = (List<DateTime>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < filename.Count; i++)
        {
            File.SetLastWriteTime(filename[i], fileDate[i]);
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Let me know, if it works.

Comment: for the first time you just serialize the data, while changing back the dates, comment serialization and uncomment deserialization